# finding the remainder of $(x+1)^7+x^5+(x-1)^3$ divided by $ x+2$

Tags: polynomials

How can i find the remainder of $(x+1)^7+x^5+(x-1)^3$ divided by $x+2$?

I tried long division but it's really messy.

Also i saw that $x=0$ is a root but it still difficult.

Comment: i got $78066$ as the searched result

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner  If you use modular arithmetic, we have      (x+1)^7+x^5+(x-1)^3== -60 (mod(x+2))

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hint: write $f(x) = Q(x). (x-a) + R(x)$, where $Q$ is the quotient and $R$ the remainder. Then:

1. what is the possible degree of $R$ ?
2. what is the link between the values $f(a)$ and $R(a)$ ?

This should solve your problem quite easily!

Comment: what is $a$? honestly i didn't get the hint..

Comment: that is, if you know, using the Remainder Theorem.

Comment: i just know long division in it's technical way.

Comment: @abi The hint is to guide you to a proof of the [Polynomial Remainder Theorem.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polynomial_remainder_theorem)  That should have been taught before your exercise.

Comment: i saw now the link but still didn't get how to proceed

Comment: i got it thanks!